# Problems with one Umbraco instance, multiple sites, on Azure

Tags: azure, umbraco7

I am trying to work out how to host multiple sites on one instance of Umbraco, which is hosted on Azure. I've added the second domain as a custom domain on the Azure Web App. I've created two Home pages at the root of my Umbraco and set each to the appropriate hostname in 'Culture and Hostnames'. I can still navigate to the original site, but when I try to go to the second site I get the following error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params string[])'

No offending source code is identified.

I don't really know what I'm doing with this and try as I might I can't find any answers by googling the issue.

Comment: This looks like a problem in your template, maybe calling UmbracoHelper.Media somewhere with an empty parameter?. Are you sure this is caused by the second website? I've had no problem running multiple websites in the same azure web app

Comment: I assume it is the second website as the first still operates ok. The only reference to media I can find in the Template is `<img src="@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.logoimage).Url" />`. The problem couldn't be something to do with the fact I'm on Azure, could it?

Comment: btw, sorry it is taking so long for me to respond - I'm only in once a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I had a Partial View that allows you to add some logos to the bottom of the homepage and as I was only doing a test run I hadn't added the logos in. So Umbraco was looking for images that weren't there and threw the error. Thanks for your pointer Mark.

Comment: Now I can move on to the next problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073450/different-stylesheets-for-umbraco-multisite